# How to get count of files in directory using command,exe in c# app

Tags: shell, ms-dos, c#

I want to use the Process class to execute a command.exe method to return the number of files in a parent directory.

It has to be using the command.exe (various reasons).

This is my code:

```
    private static Int64 GetFileCount(string path)
    {
        Int64 ct = 0;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "dir \"" + path + "\" /s/a-d | find /c \".dat\"";
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        if (output != "")
        {
            ct = Convert.ToInt64(output);
        }
        process.WaitForExit();
        return ct;
    }
```

the path variable is:

```
d:\Cloud\Catalogues\0\2015
```

I have copied this and executed it in a dos prompt and It works OK so I know the DOS stuff works.

This is what I have copied and run in a DOS/Command prompt:

```
dir "d:\Cloud\Catalogues\0\2015" /s/a-d | find /c ".dat"
```

I have used other DOS commands in my C# app and it all works well.

The result is always an empty string {""}.

It is just this 'find' function I am having an issue with.

I know I could use a bat file but for simplicity I would prefer to use the above.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The actual problem seems to be that you're using the wrong arguments. add '/k' or '/c' when you want to execute the commands you have put in the Arguments string.

Old, may still be relevant:
Assuming you have *very good* reasons not use the System.IO namespace to get the information you want the non-hacky native way, I think it's the fact that you're trying to run without ShellExecute, which means that you have to provide the full path to the executable you're trying to execute (in this case cmd.exe), as the command is not executed in a shell and therefore does not have environment variables available needed to expand the location of cmd.exe.

That said I have not tested this, I'm on Linux and generally develop in Mono. SuperUser wouldn't let me add my two cents without a full Answer because I don't have enough reputation, but I still felt I should add my two cents.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur thoughts. I will be able test this in 2hrs when I get back. And yes there r reasons which r not on my control

Comment: Hi, just gave it a go.  When I change the ShellExecute = true I get : The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.

Comment: You cannot use UseShellExecute when you're redirecting the standard output/input, no. You have to provide the full path to cmd (e.g C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe). Note that you CAN use environment variables if you need them, by calling them in the C# code with Environment.SpecialFolder or Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables().

Comment: So, a wee bit confused then. How can i get the result into a C# variable if I cannot redirect the SO?

Comment: You can, just you have to provide the full path to the executable instead of just 'cmd.exe' as you're not executing the command in a shell.

Comment: Hi, OK, I just did that but still no joy I am afraid

Comment: Oh I also realized, your arguments for cmd don't make sense; basically C# will put what you put there behind cmd.exe as parameters. To execute something you need to do something like "/k dir" instead of just dir right away since cmd won't interpret that and thus won't return any data since it'll just wait for input.

Comment: Well done!  I did have /c if my other dir command but did not transpse it over. A well deserved answer!

Comment: I'll move the actual answer to the answer then :) I'm glad it worked out for you! You should slap whoever's responsible for forcing you to use dir instead of System.IO ;)

Comment: Yh, that's cool.  Old school programmer who runs the team...